# adding hover and onclick effect for sliding images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, hover

I'm using a jQuery script for sliding images on my [website](http://www.planzone.fr/). I don't know how to fix my `hover` (now it just slides by 1 logo when I need to slide until mouseout) and `click` effect (which slide by 1 logo) for my "next" and "prev" buttons.

Here is the JavaScript for 2 buttons that I've tried:

```
if(o.btnPrev)
        $(o.btnPrev).click(function() {
            return go(curr-o.scroll);
        });

    if(o.btnNext)
        $(o.btnNext).click(function() {
            return go(curr+o.scroll);
        });

    if(o.btnGo)
        $.each(o.btnGo, function(i, val) {
            $(val).click(function() {
                return go(o.circular ? o.visible+i : i);
            });
        });
```

**EDIT** - I found out how to add `hover` and `click` events to my buttons, but I still need to add a `hover` effect on the button that slides logos until `mouseout`. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

**EDIT-2** - there is new jq code, and what i need now is to scroll my logos when mouse is over the arrows until its out,so i want that when im on the arrows its scrolls the logos 1by1 until the coursor is out, for the moment i need to go out and go on the arrow to scroll the next logo and i need also to add the speed of scrolling on mouseover, thnaks..
New JQ scritp for buttons

```
if(o.btnPrev)
        $('#previous').click (function () {
            return go(curr-o.scroll);
        });

    if(o.btnNext)
        $('#next').click (function ()  {
            return go(curr+o.scroll);
        });

    if(o.btnGo)
        $.each(o.btnGo, function(i, val) {
            $(val).click (function()  {
                return go(o.circular ? o.visible+i : i);
         });
```

});

```
    if(o.btnPrev)
        $('#previous').mouseover(function () {
            return go(curr-o.scroll);
        });

    if(o.btnNext)
        $('#next').mouseover(function ()  {
            return go(curr+o.scroll);
        });

    if(o.btnGo)
        $.each(o.btnGo, function(i, val) {
            $(val).mouseover(function()  {
                return go(o.circular ? o.visible+i : i);
         });

    });
```

and here is JSFiddle with full JQ Script : http://jsfiddle.net/Lfy6Y/21/

Comment: Why not use a tool that is already available? http://wowslider.com/rq/jquery-images-gallery/

Comment: Also, this is sometimes called an image "conveyor." There are plenty of tutorials online if you Google that.

Comment: I find it, but i still need help for 1  more thing, i edited my quastion. thanx

Comment: i add this " .bind('click mouseover', function () " to my buttons in jq script

Comment: "click mouseover" is not an event. Try just using `mouseover`. Also, if that is jQuery then you should be using the `.on(event, function)` method instead.

Comment: And if you are using jQuery, you could just use the `.mouseover()` method (docs: http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)

Comment: but if i use only mousover ill lose the posibility of clicing on my button?

Comment: Use one binding for the `click` event and a **separate** bind for the `mouseover` event. Different event bindings will not override eachother.

Comment: Feel free to post a JSFiddle if you get stuck; peeps at SO like JSFiddles. G'luck.

Comment: and do you know how to make mouseover events to slide my logos until mouse is out and not every time need to passe over the button to slide next one, thanks?

Comment: That depends on how you write your function. The `mouseover` event will continue to be called until you move your mouse outside of the affected element.

Comment: here is JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lfy6Y/5/

Comment: i just do that u said, and its work just for click event and not for mousover

Comment: Your code is a bit of a jungle, bud. Could you try simplifying it down to the *core* mouseover pieces? That might help you debug as well...

Comment: i find my mistake, it didnt work for mouseover bcs i make a error when i close my function i colse it to late, but now i dont know what i need to add to mouseover event fonction that allow me to scroll my logos when my mouse is over until is out, thanks if you can help me?

Comment: Update your fiddle with your new code (and put the link in the question). Also explain *in your question* what your current obstacle is.

Comment: I update the fiddle with the new code and edit my question, so i wait for your answer cos im stuck and cant find the solution for this, thanks

Comment: I posted a simplified, functional example to show what I *think* you're trying to achieve. Lemme know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There are a few funky things in your Fiddle.**

1.) You're not declaring a `mouseover` event for the scrolling buttons. *If you want something to happen on mouseover, you need to declare it.*

2.) Your code is cluttered; that's going to be a pain to debug. *I'll explain the process step-by-step and we'll make an ugly (but functional) demo so you can expand.*

**How to Think of the Problem**

You want two buttons each with their own `click`, `mouseenter`, and `mouseout` calls. The click is pretty self-explanatory. The hover effect created by the `mouseenter` and `mouseout` events will need to use `setInterval` to repeat the "cycle" action.

Let's use *simple* HTML to get the idea across:

```
<div id="leftButton">Left</div>

<div id="conveyor">
    <img src="..." />
    <img src="..." />
    <img src="..." />
</div>

<div id="rightButton">Right</div>
```

**We'll break the JavaScript into pieces.** First, let's define a function to cycle the images left and another to cycle them right:

```
function cycleRight() {
    var lastImg = $("#conveyor").find("img").last();
    lastImg.remove();
    $("#conveyor").prepend(lastImg);
}
function cycleLeft() {
    var firstImg = $("#conveyor").find("img").first();
    firstImg.remove();
    $("#conveyor").append(firstImg);   
}
```

Next, let's bind those functions to the click events for the buttons:

```
//If we click either button, let's cycle the conveyor.
$("#rightButton").click(cycleRight);
$("#leftButton").click(cycleLeft);
```

We're going to need to think about the hover in two steps -- the mouse *over* and the mouse *out*. For each step, we'll set or clear a timer variable that will give the conveyor the effect we want. Let's call that variable `hoverCycle`.

First, the `mouseover`:

```
//The mouse-enter (ie: the *start* of the hover)
$("#rightButton").on("mouseenter", function() {
    clearInterval(hoverCycle);
    hoverCycle = setInterval(cycleRight, 200);
});
$("#leftButton").on("mouseenter", function() {
    clearInterval(hoverCycle);
    hoverCycle = setInterval(cycleLeft, 200);
});
```

And finally the `mouseout` -- which only needs to clear the `hoverCycle` variable:

```
//The mouse-out (ie: the *end* of the hover)
$("#rightButton").on("mouseout", function() {
    clearInterval(hoverCycle);
});
$("#leftButton").on("mouseout", function() {
    clearInterval(hoverCycle);
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cfalk/A5mEA/)**

**Note: This isn't pretty, but I've left you room to expand.**